# React native maps MapView.onPress not always triggered

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

When using react-native-maps with Google maps on iOS, when I click on a city name on the map, the onPress event is not triggered.

My code sample :

```
onPress = () => {
  console.warn('pressed');
}

render() {
  return (
    <MapView
      onPress={ this.onPress }
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    />
  );
}
```

Versions :

- react-native : 0.55.4
- react-native-maps : 0.23.0

Does anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who was interest by the response. It is only because onPress on map is not used when you click on a POI (city names seems to be poi on the map...)

To handler press everywhere on the map, the onPoiClick must be filled too...